# How do I install and select cursor themes?

Tags: 11.10, themes, cursor

I'm new to this amazing OS (Ubuntu 11.10) and I've been changing a lot of things and experimenting (it's fun you know).

But I don't know how to install cursor themes.
Can I install this? http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Aero+Mouse+Cursors+with+Drop+Shadow?content=67833

If it's possible, how do you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing the theme is pretty simple. Simply extract the folder in the archive to `~/.icons` (the ~/ represents your home folder, and .icons is a hidden directory).

Then, install Ubuntu-Tweak from here: https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/next, and use that to change your cursor theme.

Comment: Mr. Roland I'm SOOOO grateful with your answer!!

I could have never known that it was sooo easy!

Thank you very much (and I hope this will help a lot of people like me).

Greetings from Bogotá, D.C.

Comment: @Alejosz: As an alternative, you can also use GNOME Tweak Tool to set the cursor theme.

Comment: You can also install Ubuntu-Tweak from the software center in 12.04 stable release. The only issue with that is you have to disable the CD ROm option in the software sources tab. Also note that many of the cursor themes work within certain contexts like a browser or text editor. But oddly enough, they don't work within the unity desktop environment (it defaults to the original cursor).