# x11 mouse themes not showing on desktop (unity)

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, mouse, x11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and select cursor themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74560/how-do-i-install-and-select-cursor-themes)

Hi I have install a few different themes for the mouse cursor. They work well except on the desktop, taskbar or unity launcher where it defaults to the original theme.

Any help with this is much appreciated...

Comment: Having the same issue.  This is not a duplicate, I'm amazed five separate people are so poor with their reading comprehension.  :/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart some applications for the new theme to work. If you log out, and then log back in, the new cursors should show in those areas, rather than the old one.

Comment: I have tried It works fine in applications its just with the desktop. Will post screenshot

Comment: Sorry cant do screen shot dose not show cursor

Comment: You can select show cursor when doing the shot with gnome-screenshooter