# How do I add custom cursor themes in xfce4?

Tags: xfce, cursor-theme

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS on my Toshiba Chromebook 2 and I am attempting to add a new cursor theme to xfce 4.8. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install and select cursor themes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74560/how-do-i-install-and-select-cursor-themes)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cursor themes need to be placed in `~/.icons` then they will show up in **Settings > Mouse and Touchpad > Theme**

Comment: Yeah thanks, it doesn't seem to show themes placed in `~/.local/share/icons` or `/usr/local/share/icons` ...