# Why if I change my cursor, point to the launcher or the top bar, the cursor gets back to the original ones?

Tags: unity, launcher, reset, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change mouse cursor and theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme)

Why if I change my cursor in my Virtual Machine, point to the launcher or the top bar, the cursor gets back to the original ones?
Then when when I come out of the launcher or top bar it is back to my selected cursor?