# Installed mouse cursor theme but it only shows in some applications

Tags: themes, cursor

I went [here](http://gnome-look.org/) and downloaded a theme named Ubuntaero_v1.0. 
Then I extracted the files to /usr/share/icons.
After rebooting the system, the default cursor theme remains, except when moving the mouse over some applications' windows, such as KeepassX.

However, when I take a screenshot of that same window, the outcome shows the default cursor again.

Then I went to terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

The ubuntaero theme is not listed.
It seems I am missing something in installing a cursor theme. What could it be?

Comment: See if [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme) helps.

Comment: Hello, not really, I've tried different methods but none of them make a consistent change in all applications. The closest I've been to that was to follow these instructions http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1974227&page=2, given by Dennis N, making use of "galternatives". All cursors were changed to aero except the main one, which turned into a black cursor. Also the main cursor remained the default DMZ-white in some windows, for example when an app is asking for password. Install a mouse theme is proving to be much more complicated and time wasting than it should...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change the permission of extracted directory (including sub-directories and files) to 755:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 cursors/
```

Then change the theme presented in `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme` to your Cursor theme

Then Select it in `gnome-tweak-tool`

I've tried every instructions and it didn't work (default Arrow cursor remained DMZ-White), until i changed the permission.

Hope it helps.