# How to change the cursor in Unity, oxygen theme?

Tags: unity, themes, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change mouse cursor and theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme)

How do I change the cursor of the theme?