# Changing the X11 default pointer size

Tags: cursor

The mechanism for changing the cursor *theme* has been outlined in answers to other questions such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66843/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-and-theme).

Moreover, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126491/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-and-its-size?lq=1) contains the procedure that I use. In case you don't want to follow the link it works something like this:

1) Run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme` This changes the "default" pointer.

2) Launch `dconf-editor` and change `org.gnome.desktop.interface.cursor-theme` to the theme you want.

Even more condensed we have:

1) Set the X11 pointer

2) Set the GTK/Gnome/Unity Pointer

So here's the rub: using these methods, I can set the size for GTK/Gnome, but the update-alternatives method just allows for changing the theme, not the size.

The feeling I get from reading various forums seems to be "just install a different cursor theme which has the size you want as a default." Is this actually the current state of affairs?

P.S. In case it matters, I'm using the dmz-cursor-theme which claims that the cursors are in a "scalable format."

Comment: you might need to scale them manually in a program like inkscape

Answer (score 0):

Or Launch `dconf-editor` and change `org.gnome.desktop.interface.cursor-size`